# Class constructor cannot be invoked without new

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, module

i am new with object oriented programming and more special with nodejs , i ve tried to redirect routing to an other class but i always found this problem when try to call this route

> TypeError: Class constructor Router cannot be invoked without 'new'

i ve tried many different ways but it didn't work

```
//this is the fuction exists into the app.js

const index = require('./serverSide/router/index');
initRoutes() {
      app.use('/admin', index);
    app.use('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + './src/index.html');
    });
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        const err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
    });
}

//and this is into the class Router

class Router {
    constructor(router) {
       console.log('/**Routing**/');
       router.get('/', this.result());
    }
    result(req, res) {
      console.log("works");
    }
 }

 module.exports = Router;
```

Comment: app.js calls the Router class?

Comment: yeah exactly it does

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `new` on a class when you're including a `constructor`. For more information here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes